# como subir imagen en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

quisiera subir una imagen y no se como crear el codigo  en laravel asi tengo el blade

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y eso funciona? te da error? cual es la pregunta?

Comment: como creo el codigo para subir la imagen

Answer (score 3):

Primero en tu form tienes que poner esto `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

después tu input

```
<input id="file-input" name="imagenesperfil" type="file"/>
```

después tu controlador aquí te pongo dividido solo para subir la imagen

```
        $file = $request->file('imagenperfil');
        //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
        $nombre =  time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
        //indicamos que queremos guardar un nuevo archivo en el disco local
        \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre,  \File::get($file));

        $archivo = new Archivos;
        $archivo->nombre_archivo = $nombre;
        $archivo->save();
```

algo que te recomiendo usar es el filesystems.php ubicado en la carpeta de config que contiene laravel para que tengas un mejor control de donde se van almacenar tus archivos si puedes observar

```
\Storage::disk('imagenperfil')->put($nombre,  \File::get($file));
```

donde dice disk imagenperfil es por que estoy haciendo referencia a imagenperfil dentro de filesytem que contiene esto

```
   'imgperfil' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/proyecto/images/imagenes-perfil',
    ],
```

espero te funcione

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar imagenes en laravel desde un formulario se podria utilizar la etiqueta `input` de esta manera:

```
<input accept="image/*" type="file" name="imagen" >
```

la etiqueta `type` nos permitira seleccionar una imagen de nuestro ordenador y utilización `accept` estaremos validando que solo sean archivos tipo jpg, png. Esto para la parte de la vista, para el controlador se puede utilizar:

```
 $image = $request->file('imagen');
 $image->move('uploads', $image->getClientOriginalName());
 $nombre_tabla->imagen = image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Esto nos permitira primero recueperar el archivo que subimos, luego lo moveremos a la carpeta uploads que deberemos crear en la carpeta `public`, la funcion getClientOriginalName nos permitira Recuperar el nombre original de un archivo cargado y finalmente guardaremos la direccion de la imagen en la base de datos en un capo tipo `string`. Espero haber podido responder tu pregunta